# excel tooltips in reporting services

Tags: excel, reporting-services

Its is possible to recreate same logic like in this excel on reporting services platform ?

If we have same values its shows blank values and when we point, on this value it will show us tooltip like in picture (it is table with information about member in this case)

[tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81GIL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tooltip property in any textbox.

You can use expressions to fill the tooltip with the required data.

[image]

Result will look like the image below

[image]

Comment: its possible to add to this tooltip all MEM member table ? (in my dataset which i created in sql, i have left joined this table to my fact table)

Comment: how i can add many information to my tooltip ?

Comment: You can use the fields in the expression for the tooltip. I have updated my example